# Does Repository have just the index of Packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am novice user, wanting to get basic knowledge.

The question is about Repository.

My understanding:

·Repository:One of the directories in the Ubuntu 
 installed computer.

·Package:Stored in the Repository to be used to 
  install applications.

Then my question is that Repository has just 
the index of applications or tools?

From a different angle, can I install any general application without the online connection?

Are all binary-files needed for any installation already stored as packages in Repository?

If so, is a lot of date  downloaded to replace old binary-files of applications to new ones of them when I type the command "sudo apt-get update"?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, which is faster than MOOCs' discussion sections!  I'll check it.

Comment: Suggested link tell me things below. 

The 4 types of repository exist in servers somewhere, so they are not local directories, though a copy of Canonical repository could be set in the local strage, if users needed.  

My knowledge advanced. I will carefully deside whether any PPA should be added or not if I want some additional function, because they are located out of 4 main repositories. I appreciate your support!